# Access a function in main executable from dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, clang, address-sanitizer

I need to link ASAN dynamically on Windows, and I want to provide default options via `__asan_default_options`.

```
#include <sanitizer/asan_interface.h>

__attribute__((used))
__attribute__((no_sanitize_address))
const char* __asan_default_options(void) {
  return "log_path=asan.log";
}
```

If I link ASAN statically (/MT) everything works fine. But in dynamic setup (/MD) ASAN.dll does not see `__asan_default_options` defined in main executable.

According to the source code of ASAN, it seems to support such "weak" symbols. But unfortunately, my `__asan_default_options` is being ignored.

I use `clang-cl` and `lld-link.exe`.

```
cflags: /MD -Xclang -fsanitize=address
ldflags: /LIBPATH:c:\path\to\LLVM8.0.0\lib\clang\8.0.0\lib\windows \
      clang_rt.asan-x86_64.lib \
      clang_rt.asan_cxx-x86_64.lib
```

How is it possible to pass options using `__asan_default_options` declared in main executable?

Comment: Have you exported `__asan_default_options`?

Comment: @WilliamClements `__asan_default_options` is described at your link.

Comment: @WilliamClements Sorry, still fail to see how it is relevant to OP's question (he specifically needs to provide _default_ value of flags, which can be overriden by `ASAN_OPTIONS` if needed).